# Is it possible to retrieve the release notes from Google Play Store or "symlink" what I generated with fastlane so I can display it in my app?

Tags: android, kotlin, fastlane

I use `fastlane supply` for generating my app metadata that I publish to the play store. The generated files are stored in the `metadata` folder in my repository's root directory. It's there in the metadata directory where the release notes for my next version is updated.

However, I also want to show these release notes in my app. So is there a way I can programatically retrieve them?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the changelog String content from a remote origin file using a simple API request. So Imagine if you have a file at this path

```
https://github.com/androidbuffer/Kotlinfilepicker/blob/master/README.md
```

then you can simply hit below URL to get the raw content

```
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/androidbuffer/Kotlinfilepicker/master/README.md
```

this will give you the String content from the file and you can parse it and arrange it to display the contents.

Possibility:

1) You can use Firebase to store your changelogs and then retrieve them in-app using their SDK. but I assume you want it to be automatically uploaded from the **metadata** folder then you can write some Gradle script to upload the content of the file to the firebase storage and retrieve them in your app. This will be a better approach otherwise you have to do it manually.

2) But if your repository is closed then you need to log in to the source control provider and then request the content but it will be too much just for this simple thing.

Comment: Isn't there something like play store api for this? My app is public anyway.

Comment: @Altus here is google console api guide. may this will help.
https://developers.google.com/android-publisher